# opening phonegap camera from within browser

Tags: browser, cordova

I have a mobile website (on a remote server) made with jquery mobile (front-end) and laravel backend. In phonegap i have made an app that opens a browser and displays the mobile website.

In the mobile website i have two buttons:

[Mobile upload]
[Normal upload]

The normal upload button chooses an image from from your computer with laravel(or some other framework).
The Mobile upload buttons needs to call the phonegap camera. So the user can select a image from the phone. Then using file transfer send it to the site again.

Is this possible to call Phonegap functions from a website inside the browser?
And what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

To access the camera roll on your phone, you just need to create a normal file input.

```
<input type="file" id="fileProfileImage" accept="image/*" capture />
```

On iPhone you can use image/* to select only images.

In your JS code, I will suggest you to use this plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload 
It can upload files cross domain. I don't know anything about laravel, but you will have to create a CORS enabled webservice that can handle your upload request. I've done it in .net, and its a pain to get work correctly.

Here are the JS code I use to upload my files in phonegap (with the plugin I linked to):

```
$('#fileProfileImage').fileupload(
        {
            url: "WEBSERVICE URL",
            dataType: 'json',
            //forceIframeTransport: true,
            formData: { someProp: "someVal" },
            start: function (e, data)
            {

            },
            done: function (e, data)
            {

            },
            progressall: function (e, data)
            {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $("#alert p span").text(progress); //this shows the progress in %
            },
            fail: function (e, data)
            {

            }
        });
```

The code is not phonegap specific. It can be implemented in every browser, and it works well in phonegap.